# Using GCM with Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

what is the best way to use GCM from google with meteor together? 
There are much plugins with some sample code but I don't know what is the best to use. Also a full example of an plugin would be nice. I need to send push messages from the server to the clients. on android and ios. (Want to use it for a chat)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [raix:push](https://github.com/raix/push) meteor package.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out meteor can add a cordova plugin as if it were a package.

```
meteor add cordova:<plugin id>@https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/tarball/<commit>
```

So you can use the plugin (https://github.com/uriva/PushPlugin)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Cordova plugin, [this](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-integration) is a documentation about Meteor cordova integration which explains how to create meteor apps for Android and iOs, For the GCM push messages you can use meteor packages like raix:push.